# Calling for values for the solver in vba

Tags: vba, solver

How should I call for cells in vba to get the solver working? I'd like to build a loop where the rows change but I don't seem to get any output in the cell that should change (by letting "a" grow).
Why is this?

What I do is want to pick out certain values in columns and ask the macro to find the text and then the values below them.

```
 Sub CalculateValues() 
       SolverReset

       a = 1

       SolverOptions Precision:=0.00001, AssumeNonNeg:=False
       SolverOk SetCell:=Cells.Find("Total energy").Offset(1 + a, 0).Activate, MaxMinVal:=3, ValueOf:=Cells.Find("8 bar needed").Offset(1 + a, 0).Activate, ByChange:=Cells.Find("VO4VO5").Offset(1 + a, 0).Activate
       SolverSolve userFinish:=True

End Sub
```

Comment: As far as I remember you need to use cell address. So, instead of cell reference like `Cells.Find("Total energy").Offset(1 + a, 0).Activate` try `Cells.Find("Total energy").Offset(1 + a, 0).Address`, or just something like: `A1` or `E15`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It did unfortunately not work with "Address". I do, in some way, need to call it in a general way as I'd like to add a few loops to this statement.

Comment: I hope you changed it three times?! Now I'm sure, it must got according to the following syntax: `SolverOk SetCell:=Cells.Find("Total energy").Offset(1 + a, 0).Address, MaxMinVal:=3, ValueOf:=Cells.Find("8 bar needed").Offset(1 + a, 0).Address, ByChange:=Cells.Find("VO4VO5").Offset(1 + a, 0).Address`

Comment: My apologies.  "Address" was the correct term. That was one problem and the other was to change the focus cell. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The changed line which now works is:

SolverOk setCell:=Cells.Find("Error").Offset(1 + a, 0).Address, MaxMinVal:=3, ByChange:=Cells.Find("VO4VO5").Offset(1 + a, 0).Address

Where the "Error" should become zero.